# Maintaining .net mvc session from classic asp pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, asp-classic, isapi

As a requirement our team has to implement session management for our application, redirecting users to the login page on session expiry. The problem is the website is a mixture of classic asp pages, .net web forms and asp.net mvc.

To keep the .net session alive we can use http GET requests to a dummy controller method that will redirect to the login page if the session has expired.

Because there are a considerable amount of page in the application it would be good to avoid having to put an include file on each page to refresh the .net session on each page load. Also for each ajax request made from classic asp we want to refresh the .net session.

An ideal solution to this would be to intercept each request made to the server, pass them through the dummy controller method to refresh the .net session, redirecting the user if the session has expired. I have looked at creating an ISAPI module for this as a possibility but am still unsure of the workload involved in creating such a module, or if I can create the desired behavior.

Is anyone in a similar situation or have a concrete solution to this problem?

Comment: try looking into the Application_AcquireRequestState in global.asax. you can intercept all the requests here.

Comment: Wont this only intercept the requests sent to that application, not the whole website?

Comment: yeah it will only intercept the requests sent to the MVC application.